# How to get this symbol about normal group?

Tags: symbols

General input  normal group use `$\unlhd$` or `$\trianglelefteq$`,

[image]

I want to get the two symbols in LaTeX:

[image]

(I see it at **P.Grillet. "Abstract Algebra". 2nd ed**, GTM242)

It's like another symbol `$\leqq$` and `$\lneqq$`, and I hope know that how to get
I hope them seem like adding a vertical line to `$\leqq$` or `$\lneqq$`, so that the size is relatively close to `$\leqq$` or `$\lneqq$`.

I want to know how to get these two symbols in a simple way.

Comment: Welcome to the site! For your question, try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: why this question was downvoted?

Comment: I have no clear my problem, can you see again?

Comment: I reopened the question: the requested symbols cannot be found in the linked resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this ( if you want to modify vertical position of symbols just change parameter for `\lower` inside `\triaeq` and `\triaNeq` commands ).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\setbox0=\hbox{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\vartriangleleft$}\vskip0.2ex\hbox{$=$}}}

\setbox1=\hbox{\vbox {\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\vartriangleleft$}\vskip0.2ex\hbox{$\neq$}}}

\def\triaeq{\lower 0.3\ht0\copy0}
\def\triaNeq{\lower 0.3\ht1\copy1}

\begin{document}

text text text \\
text $\triaeq$ text $\triaNeq$ text

\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newbox{\boxA}
\newbox{\boxB}


\setbox\boxA\hbox{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\vartriangleleft$}\vskip0.15ex\hbox{$=$}}}

\setbox\boxB\hbox{\vbox {\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\vartriangleleft$}\vskip-0.3ex\hbox{$\nequal$}}}

\def\triaeq{\lower0.3\ht\boxA\copy\boxA}
\def\triaNeq{\lower0.3\ht\boxB\copy\boxB}

\begin{document}

-- $\leqq$ \qquad  $\lneqq$ \qquad $\triaeq$ \qquad $\triaNeq$ --

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to use boxes 0 and 1 like that on a global scope? I would expect them to get overwritten by some random package.

Comment: I think it is very close to my needs and it looks easy to understand. Thanks

Comment: I find a better way that the code is '\renewcommand\unlhd{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\leqq$\cr\raise.5ex\hbox{$\lhd$}\cr}}}'